# Why does the curl command fail becuase of the 56890 port?

Tags: curl, connection

When I use curl command to post data via an API it says that

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 56890: Connection refused

And I also have tried to download a page but get the same information.

I learned from [this document](http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/56890) and also [this](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=56890) that port 56897 is a TCP port but not a registered one. And from this doc that it is failed because of the proxy or host. I think I may once set that port to something.

From the output of `netstat -tuplen` I cannot find the 56890 port is being used.

Could anyone please tell me how I can make the port work?

Comment: Do you have any server program listening to this port and accepting connections?

Comment: Yes I once was running a server and I may forget to close that. How can I find that server and close it?

Comment: try `netstat -tulpn | grep :56890`

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko I got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason could be that your application or service is not up and running on port `56890`

To check what indeed is running you could use:

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P
```

Not for doing a basic test or launch a small web server to listen on port `56890` you could you could use [www](https://github.com/nbari/www)

```
$ www -p 56890
2017/09/09 11:03:37 Listening on port: 56890
```

Or you could also just use netcat:

```
$ nc -kl 56890
```

The `-k` Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.

And test:

```
$ curl 0:56890
```

If using netcat you can test with telnet:

```
$ telnet 0 56890
```

Also, check your `~/.curlrc`, probably there is something defined (a proxy) that may not allow you to connect

Comment: I cannot find that port in the list after I enter `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P`.

Comment: then is nothing is up and running on that port, if you just want to open something on that port give a try to [www](https://dl.bintray.com/nbari/www/)

Comment: The system I am using is Ubuntu, then I cannot use www.

Comment: No curlrc dot file there.

Comment: I updated the answer so that you could also test with netcat, not a web server but at least will open something on port 56890

Comment: In the test(`curl 0:56890`) while running `nc -kl 56890` I find that the value of Proxy-Connection is keep-alive. Is that where the problem lies?

Comment: Now try with www since being a web server may respond properly to curl, at least now you have something listed on port 56890